# Application doesn't submit form after setInterval method in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Application doesn't submit form after setInterval method.
If I'd clicked button "BUY" (in 5 second) before setInterval method, then everything is fine, the form will send out.
But after 5 second, when data will refresh by setInterval method then nothing happens if I click on "BUY" button.

Main view:

```
<div id="ListTable">
    @{Html.RenderAction("_ListPartial");}
</div>

<script>
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#ListTable").load('@Url.Action("_ListPartial","Home",null)');
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

_ListPartial view:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        .
        .
        .
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Shop", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    @Html.Hidden("ItemId", item.ItemId)
                </td>
                .
                .
                .
                <td>
                          <input type="submit" value="Buy" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What if you put your `setInterval` inside a `.ready()` function?

Comment: Still doesn't work  :(
<script>
    ready(function() { setInterval ... <script>
In console i have error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ready is not defined".

Comment: Is  _ListPartial the name of the action in Home controller?

Comment: Yes. As i said before refresh data by setInterval - all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout` after the request is complete

```
function sendRequest() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'URL',
  dataType: "json",
  complete: function(xhr, statusText) {
   setTimeout('sendRequest', 1000);
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   alert("success: ");
  },
  error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   alert("error");
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
 });
}
```

**If the content takes more than 1 second to load, you'll have multiple requests in queue.**

Comment: "/** your post data code **/" - im not sure what u mean? What exactly should I paste here?